# Queries around Nsubstitute and unit tests

Tags: c#, .net, nsubstitute

I am trying to change my Mocking framework from Moq to Nsubstitute following the recent changes to the Moq package.

I've found it easy enough to turn new Mock into Substitute.For but in trying to change my unit tests' base class I'm finding it quite difficult.

As part of the setup I am doing something like this:

```
mockInstance = _mockRepository.Create<TMock>();
```

and then swapping out the real implementation of my Startup with a mocked version (i.e. the mockInstance).

I noticed that there is a "SubstituteFactory" that has a "Create" method, much like there is a "MockRepository" that has a create method (from Moq).. however this method takes "Type[] typesToProxy" and "object?[] constructorArguments" which is where I'm having some trouble because I can't find any examples or API documentation around this class, even though it comes from Nsubstitute.Core.

I thought perhaps this could be an internal class used by the package and not intended for use by package consumers?

Any advice to point me in the right direction is much appreciated

Comment: eeeeehm, what *is* `mockRepository`? Why not just use `Substitute.For<TMock>()`?

Comment: Sorry - mockRepository is from Moq, which I believe just creates
Mock<T>. My dependency setup didn't seem to allow me to simply use Substite.For<TMock> but I just went back and changed some of my signatures around and that does actually seem to work (or at least the project builds - need to rewrite my tests to ensure there's no strange runtime issues)... Apologies for the non-issue on my part, but I got there in the end!

Comment: you're welcome. I'm with you. With NSubsitute you'd never actually work with the mock itself as you do with moq. Instead you're allways using extension-methods, so the notion of a `new Mock<T>` doesn't exist.